# For each loop with multiple variables

Tags: ansible

I'm running a javaprogram with shell module to iterate over a list of users, for each user I want to loop through a number of groups to add to each user.

I'm not looking to add new users/groups to the OS but to a program that runs on the server.

All users in USER_LIST should be added to all groups in GROUP_LIST.

Non working example:

```
vars: 
GROUP_LIST:
- DATA
- ONE
- TWO

USER_LIST:
- USER1
- USER2
- USER3

- name: add all users to all groups
  shell:
  cmd: |
    java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g {{GROUP_LIST}} {{item}} 
  loop: {{USER_LIST}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use filter [**product**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products):

```
- name: add all users to all groups
  shell:
  cmd: |
    java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g {{item.1}} {{item.0}} 
  loop: {{USER_LIST | product(GROUP_LIST) | list}}
```

for example:

```
  tasks:
    - name: list to dict
      debug: 
        msg: "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g {{item.1}} {{item.0}}"
      loop: "{{ USER_LIST | product(GROUP_LIST) | list }}"
```

gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER1', 'DATA']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g DATA USER1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER1', 'ONE']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g ONE USER1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER1', 'TWO']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g TWO USER1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER2', 'DATA']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g DATA USER2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER2', 'ONE']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g ONE USER2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER2', 'TWO']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g TWO USER2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER3', 'DATA']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g DATA USER3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER3', 'ONE']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g ONE USER3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['USER3', 'TWO']) => {
    "msg": "java -jar /opt/alt/Manager.jar mod -g TWO USER3"
}
```

following the ansible version, you have, no need to add `| list`

Comment: Right, as in Ansible documentation also explained under [Iterating over nested lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-nested-lists).

Comment: I had to add ``` | list ´´´ after product(GROUP_LIST). Otherwise the code worked fine! Cheers.

Comment: You should  have an old version of ansible

Comment: Right, I'm using 2.9. Thanks